# find $P(XY\leq 1/2)$ of a pdf

Tags: probability

I have the pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\int \frac{1}{4} dxdy$

for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$ and $ -1 \leq y \leq 1$

I need to find $P(XY \leq 1/2)$

Could someone please explain how this is done?

I have my solution at $ \frac{7}{16}-\frac{1}{16}\ln \frac{1}{2}$ but I am not sure this is correct.

Comment: title should be $P(XY \leq 1/2)$  but it is not letting me save the edit..

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your pdf.  Maybe some limits of integration would clarify.

Comment: for some reason it will not let me edit the question, the pdf should be $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}$  and the limits for x and y are given above.

Comment: i just need to know how to find the probability $P(XY \leq 1/2)$ anyway, i cannot find a similar example

Comment: I just found the whole area and minused the top half of values bigger than a half and the bottom half of values smaller than a half. Im pretty sure that I have done this wrong and there is a simple way of doing it. Could someone please tell me how to solve a problem like this? I dont necessarily need an answer, just how to do it. Many thanks

Comment: I cannot seem to edit the pdf, but it should be $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 1):

You want to integrate the pdf over its domain intersected with the region where $XY\leq 1/2$.

It may help to first graph this:
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x*y%3C.5+on+-1%3Cx%3C1+and+-1%3Cy%3C1

We see that we'll have to split this up.

$$
\int_{\{XY\leq.5\}\cap\{X\in[-1,1]\}\cap\{Y\in[-1,1]\}}=\int_{x=-1}^{-.5}\int_{y=.5/x}^1+\int_{x=-.5}^{.5}\int_{y=-1}^1+\int_{x=.5}^1\int_{y=-1}^{.5/x}
$$

These are all pretty basic.  Integrating $1/4$, we get $\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\log 2$

Comment: Amazing thank you, this is similar to what i was trying to do but i had gone wrong. Thanks!